# How use in Mule ESB session like in web app?

Tags: session, mule, esb

in Mule ESB I use Object Store, but variable in Object store is global for all connection on my TCP connection, how do it different from other connection? Like session in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a unique Object Store key as an access token you provide to each client. That's what a PHP session does: it provides a token in a cookie or the url and stores session data using that token as a key.